# You are not authorized to view this page. The transaction has not been processed

Tags: laravel, cybersource

### **I have to integrate CyberSource Payment gateway with laravel. When I click the checkout it show below error.**

```
**You are not authorized to view this page. The transaction has not been processed.
If the problem persists please report your problem and quote the following Error Reference Number:
E-5EFB6D6C58554846ACC1CB9CB1D82558**
```

This is the form I have submitted

````
     $request_form_data = [
                        "access_key" => $this->access_key,
                        "profile_id" => $this->profile_id,
                        "transaction_type" => $this->transaction_type,
                        "reference_number" => $this->reference_number,
                        "amount" => $this->amount,
                        "locale" => $this->locale,
                        "transaction_uuid" =>$this->transaction_uuid,
                        "signed_date_time" => $this->signed_date_time,
                        "signed_field_names" => "access_key,profile_id,transaction_type,reference_number,amount,locale,transaction_uuid,signed_date_time,currency",
                        "unsigned_field_names" => "",
                        "currency" => $this->currency,
                        "signature" => $this->signature,

                    ];

                    $this->signature = $this->makeSignature($request_form_data);
                    $request_form_data["signature"] = $this->signature;
                    $log_data = ["ACTION" => "PAYMENT REQUEST", "FULL_REQUEST" => $request_form_data];
                    $this->apiLog($log_data);

                    echo '
                        <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
                        <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
                            <head>
                                <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
                                <title>ShayInt Payment</title>
                            </head>
                            <body>
                                <h1 align="center">Processing your Transaction</h1>
                                <form method="post" action="' . $this->pay_url . '" name="checkout_form" style="display:none;"> 
                                    <div align="center">
                                        <input id="access_key" type="hidden" value="' . $this->access_key . '" name="access_key">
                                        <input id="profile_id" type="hidden" value="' . $this->profile_id . '" name="profile_id">
                                        <input id="transaction_type" type="hidden" value="' . $this->transaction_type . '" name="transaction_type">
                                        <input id="reference_number" type="hidden" value="' . $this->reference_number . '" name="reference_number">
                                        <input id="amount" type="hidden" value="' . $this->amount . '" name="amount" >
                                        <input id="locale" type="hidden" value="' . $this->locale . '" name="locale" >
                                        <input id="transaction_uuid" type="hidden" value="' . $this->transaction_uuid . '" name="transaction_uuid">
                                        <input id="signed_date_time" type="hidden" value="' . $this->signed_date_time . '" name="signed_date_time" >
                                        <input id="signed_field_names" type="hidden" value="' . $this->signed_field_names . '" name="signed_field_names" >
                                        <input id="unsigned_field_names" type="hidden" value="' . $this->unsigned_field_names . '" name="unsigned_field_names" >
                                        <input id="currency" type="hidden" value="' . $this->currency . '" name="currency" >
                                        <input id="signature" type="hidden" value="' . $this->signature . '" name="signature">                               
                                        <h3 align="center"> Please click on the Submit button to continue processing.<br>
                                        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
                                    </div>
                                </form>
                                <script>document.forms["checkout_form"].submit();</script>
                            </body>
                        </html>
    ```

**You are not authorized to view this page. The transaction has not been processed.
If the problem persists please report your problem and quote the following Error Reference Number:
E-5EFB6D6C58554846ACC1CB9CB1D82558**
````

Comment: Have you got any soltuion?

Please post an answer if possible with complete example.

Comment: Yes I got. I will add it here

Answer (score 1):

```
 public function proceedPaymentHNB(Request $request)
{

    $order_id = $request->input("order_id");
    $order = Order::where("id", $order_id)->first();

    if ($order_id != null && $order != null) {

        $transaction_ref = $this->addTransactionEntry($order_id);
        if ($transaction_ref != null) {
            // Transaction  created
            $this->reference_number = $transaction_ref;
            $this->amount = $order->total_amount;
            $this->bill_to_address_line1 = $order->delivery_address;
            $this->bill_to_address_city = $order->delivery_city;
            $this->bill_to_address_country = $order->delivery_country_code;
            $this->bill_to_address_postal_code = $order->delivery_delivery_zip_code;
            $this->bill_to_forename = $order->user->user_first_name;
            $this->bill_to_surname = $order->user->user_last_name;
            $this->bill_to_email = $order->user->user_email;
            $this->bill_to_phone = $order->user->user_mobile;
            $this->signed_date_time = Carbon::now()->toIso8601ZuluString(); //Carbon::now()->format("Y-m-dTh:i:sZ");
            $this->transaction_uuid = APIHelper::generateRandomString(30);

            $request_form_data = [
                "access_key" => $this->access_key,
                "profile_id" => $this->profile_id,
                "transaction_type" => $this->transaction_type,
                "reference_number" => $this->reference_number,
                "amount" => $this->amount,
                "locale" => $this->locale,
                "transaction_uuid" => $this->transaction_uuid,
                "signed_date_time" => $this->signed_date_time,
                "signed_field_names" => $this->signed_field_names,
                "unsigned_field_names" => "",
                "currency" => $this->currency,
                "payment_method" => $this->payment_method,
                "bill_to_forename" => $this->bill_to_forename,
                "bill_to_surname" => $this->bill_to_surname,
                "bill_to_email" => $this->bill_to_email,
                "bill_to_phone" => $this->bill_to_phone,
                "bill_to_address_line1" => $this->bill_to_address_line1,
                "bill_to_address_city" => $this->bill_to_address_city,
                "bill_to_address_country" => $this->bill_to_address_country,
                "bill_to_address_postal_code" => $this->bill_to_address_postal_code,
            ];

            $this->signature = $this->makeSignature($request_form_data);
            $request_form_data["signature"] = $this->signature;

            $log_data = ["ACTION" => "PAYMENT REQUEST", "FULL_REQUEST" => $request_form_data];
            $this->apiLog($log_data);

            echo '
                <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
                <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
                    <head>
                        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
                        <title>ShayInt Payment</title>
                    </head>
                    <body>
                        <h1 align="center">Processing your Transaction</h1>
                        <form method="post" action="' . $this->pay_url . '" name="checkout_form" style="display:none;"> 
                            <div align="center">
                                <input id="access_key" type="hidden" value="' . $this->access_key . '" name="access_key">
                                <input id="profile_id" type="hidden" value="' . $this->profile_id . '" name="profile_id">
                                <input id="transaction_type" type="hidden" value="' . $this->transaction_type . '" name="transaction_type">
                                <input id="reference_number" type="hidden" value="' . $this->reference_number . '" name="reference_number">
                                <input id="amount" type="hidden" value="' . $this->amount . '" name="amount" >
                                <input id="locale" type="hidden" value="' . $this->locale . '" name="locale" >
                                <input id="transaction_uuid" type="hidden" value="' . $this->transaction_uuid . '" name="transaction_uuid">
                                <input id="signed_date_time" type="hidden" value="' . $this->signed_date_time . '" name="signed_date_time" >
                                <input id="signed_field_names" type="hidden" value="' . $this->signed_field_names . '" name="signed_field_names" >
                                <input id="unsigned_field_names" type="hidden" value="' . $this->unsigned_field_names . '" name="unsigned_field_names" >
                                <input id="currency" type="hidden" value="' . $this->currency . '" name="currency" >
                                <input id="signature" type="hidden" value="' . $this->signature . '" name="signature">
                                <input id="payment_method" type="hidden" value="' . $this->payment_method . '" name="payment_method">
                                <input id="bill_to_forename" type="hidden" value="' . $this->bill_to_forename . '" name="bill_to_forename">
                                <input id="bill_to_surname" type="hidden" value="' . $this->bill_to_surname . '" name="bill_to_surname">
                                <input id="bill_to_email" type="hidden" value="' . $this->bill_to_email . '" name="bill_to_email">
                                <input id="bill_to_phone" type="hidden" value="' . $this->bill_to_phone . '" name="bill_to_phone">
                                <input id="bill_to_address_city" type="hidden" value="' . $this->bill_to_address_city . '" name="bill_to_address_city">                                    
                                <input id="bill_to_address_line1" type="hidden" value="' . $this->bill_to_address_line1 . '" name="bill_to_address_line1">                              
                                <input id="bill_to_address_country" type="hidden" value="' . $this->bill_to_address_country . '" name="bill_to_address_country">
                                <input id="bill_to_address_postal_code" type="hidden" value="' . $this->bill_to_address_postal_code . '" name="bill_to_address_postal_code">

                                <h3 align="center"> Please click on the Submit button to continue processing.<br>
                                <input type="submit" value="Submit">
                            </div>
                        </form>
                        <script>document.forms["checkout_form"].submit();</script>
                    </body>
                </html>


                ';
        } else {
            // Transaction not created
            Log::critical("Transaction not created for oder_id=" . $order_id);
            return redirect()->to(web_base_path('show-payment-response?result=error'));
        }
    } else {
        // Invalid order id
        Log::critical("Invalid order id - oder_id=" . $order_id);
        return redirect()->to(web_base_path('show-payment-response?result=error'));
    }
}

public function getPaymentGatewayResponseHNB(Request $request)
{   
    $ResponseCode = $request->input('decision');
    $ReasonCode = $request->input('reason_code');
    $ReasonCodeDesc = $request->input('message');
    $signature = $request->input('signature');
    $OrderID = $request->input('req_reference_number');
    $transaction = Transaction::where("transaction_reference", $OrderID)->first();
    $log_data = ["ACTION" => "PAYMENT RESPONSE", "DECISION" => $request->input('decision'), "ReasonCode" => $request->input('reason_code'), "ReasonCodeDesc" => $request->input('message'), "FULL_RESPONSE" => $request->input()];
    $this->apiLog($log_data);

    if (isset($ResponseCode)) {

        if ($ResponseCode == "ACCEPT") {
            if ($ReasonCode == 100) {

                // Transaction Approved.
                if ($transaction != null) {
                    $db_signature = $this->makeSignature($request);
                    $transaction->pg_response_code = $ResponseCode;
                    $transaction->pg_response_desc = $ReasonCodeDesc;
                    $transaction->pg_full_response = json_encode($request->input());
                    $transaction->save();
                    // Check signatures


                    if ($db_signature == $request->signature) {
                        // Success transaction and Signature matched
                        $transaction->order->success_transaction_id = $transaction->id;
                        $transaction->order->payment_status = 1;
                        $transaction->order->save();
                        $transaction->order->cart->status = 1;
                        $transaction->order->cart->completed_at = now()->toDateTimeString();
                        $transaction->order->cart->save();

                        //Reduce Stock
                        $reduceStock = new ProductController();
                        $reduceStock->reduceStock($transaction->order->cart->id);

                        //Change Status of Giftcard as 'purchased'
                        $cart_giftcards = CartGiftCard::where(['cart_id' => $transaction->order->cart->id])->get();
                        foreach ($cart_giftcards as $cart_giftcard) {
                            GiftCardController::purchaseGiftCard($cart_giftcard->gift_card_id);
                        }


                        // Order confirmation email to customer
                        Mail::to($transaction->order->user->user_email)->send(new CustomerOrderConfirmation($transaction->order));

                        // Order confirmation email to backend
                        Mail::to(config('shayInt.BACKEND_MAIL_ADDRESS'))->send(new BackendOrderConfirmation($transaction->order));

                        return redirect()->to(web_base_path('show-payment-response?result=success&message=' . $ReasonCodeDesc));
                    } else {
                        // Success transaction but Signature not match (BOGUS TRANSACTION)
                        Log::critical("Success transaction but Signature not match (BOGUS TRANSACTION) - Signatures=> " . $db_signature . "!=" . $signature . " Response=>" . json_encode($request->input()));
                        $transaction->order->success_transaction_id = $transaction->id;
                        $transaction->order->payment_status = 3;
                        $transaction->order->save();
                        $transaction->order->cart->status = 3;
                        $transaction->order->cart->completed_at = now()->toDateTimeString();
                        $transaction->order->cart->save();
                        return redirect()->to(web_base_path('show-payment-response?result=error&message=' . $ReasonCodeDesc));
                    }
                } else {
                    // Response OrderID not use as transaction_reference in transaction data.
                    Log::critical("Response OrderID not use as transaction_reference in transaction data.");
                    return redirect()->to(web_base_path('show-payment-response?result=error&message=' . $ReasonCodeDesc));
                }
            }
        } elseif ($ResponseCode == "CANCEL") {
            // Transaction Declined.
            Log::critical("Transaction Cancelled");
            if ($transaction != null) {
                $transaction->pg_response_code = $ResponseCode;
                $transaction->pg_response_desc = $ReasonCodeDesc;
                $transaction->pg_full_response = json_encode($request->input());
                $transaction->save();
                return redirect()->to(web_base_path('show-payment-response?result=error&message=' . $ReasonCodeDesc));
            } else {
                // Response OrderID not use as transaction_reference in transaction data.
                Log::critical("Response OrderID not use as transaction_reference in transaction data.");
                return redirect()->to(web_base_path('show-payment-response?result=error&message=' . $ReasonCodeDesc));
            }
        }elseif($ResponseCode == "DECLINE") {
            // Transaction Decline.
            Log::critical("Transaction Declined");
            if ($transaction != null) {
                $transaction->pg_response_code = $ResponseCode;
                $transaction->pg_response_desc = $ReasonCodeDesc;
                $transaction->pg_full_response = json_encode($request->input());
                $transaction->save();
                if($ReasonCode == 234||$ReasonCode == 236||$ReasonCode == 481){
                    return redirect()->to(web_base_path('show-payment-response?result=error&message='));
                }
                else{
                    return redirect()->to(web_base_path('show-payment-response?result=error&message=' . $ReasonCodeDesc));
                }

            } else {
                // Response OrderID not use as transaction_reference in transaction data.
                Log::critical("Response OrderID not use as transaction_reference in transaction data.");
                return redirect()->to(web_base_path('show-payment-response?result=error&message='));
            }
        }else {
            // Transaction Error.
            Log::critical("Transaction Error");
            if ($transaction != null) {
                $transaction->pg_response_code = $ResponseCode;
                $transaction->pg_response_desc = $ReasonCodeDesc;
                $transaction->pg_full_response = json_encode($request->input());
                $transaction->save();
                return redirect()->to(web_base_path('show-payment-response?result=error&message='));
            } else {
                // Response OrderID not use as transaction_reference in transaction data.
                Log::critical("Response OrderID not use as transaction_reference in transaction data.");
                return redirect()->to(web_base_path('show-payment-response?result=error&message='));
            }
        }
    } else {
        // Invalid response from CyberSource
        Log::critical("Invalid response from CyberSource");
        return redirect()->to(web_base_path('show-payment-response?result=error&message=' . $ReasonCodeDesc));
    }
}


private function addTransactionEntry($order_id, $currency_code = "USD")
{
    try {

        $order = Order::where('id', $order_id)->first();

        $client_ip = request()->ip();

        if ($order != null) {
            // order exists
            $transaction_ref = (string) round(microtime(true) * 1000) . rand(100, 999);

            $transaction = new Transaction();
            $transaction->order_id = $order_id;
            $transaction->user_id = $order->user_id;
            $transaction->currency_code = $currency_code;
            $transaction->amount = $order->total_amount;
            $transaction->transaction_reference = $transaction_ref;
            $transaction->pg_response_code = null;
            $transaction->pg_response_desc = null;
            $transaction->pg_full_response = null;
            $transaction->client_ip = $client_ip;
        } else {
            // order not exists
            $log_text = ["ACTION" => "PAYMENT GATEWAY INVALID ORDER ID", "CLIENT_IP" => $client_ip, "ORDER_ID" => $order_id];
            apiSecurityLog($log_text);
            return null;
        }

        if ($transaction->save()) {
            return $transaction_ref;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        Log::critical("PaymentGatewayController addTransactionEntry ERROR - Client IP = " . $client_ip);
        Log::critical($e);
        return null;
    }
}

private function makeSignature($request_form_data)
{
    return $this->signData($this->buildDataToSign($request_form_data), $this->secret_key);
}

private function signData($data, $secret_key)
{
    return base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha256', $data, $secret_key, true));
}

private function buildDataToSign($request_form_data)
{
    $signedFieldNames = explode(",", $request_form_data["signed_field_names"]);
    foreach ($signedFieldNames as $field) {
        $dataToSign[] = $field . "=" . $request_form_data[$field];
    }
    return $this->commaSeparate($dataToSign);
}

private function commaSeparate($dataToSign)
{
    return implode(",", $dataToSign);
}

private static function apiLog($log_text)
{
    $log_file_path = storage_path('logs/payment_gateway/payment.log');
    $log = [$log_text];
    $orderLog = new Logger("HNB");
    $orderLog->pushHandler(new StreamHandler($log_file_path), Logger::INFO);
    $orderLog->info('Log', $log);
}
```

}

Comment: You have to configure your cyber source account according to your needs and then add those credintials to your .env file

Comment: Would be helpful if you could also explain your code.

Comment: @ShehanLJayasinghe Can you explain what was change you did to rectify the error.

Comment: @KasunRajapaksha Error occured because I didn't add required data to the request form data. So i added thode reuired data.

Comment: @ShehanLJayasinghe Thanks, same with mine.

Comment: @ShehanLJayasinghe thank you very much. I also searched for a solution.